# how to auto populate text field in laravel?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, autocomplete

I want to add a functionality to text field, when a user types in the name it should display all the name starting with that letter from the data available in the table.

```
public function search() {

$q = Input::get('myInputField');

$searchTerms = explode(' ', $q);

$query = DB::table('products');

foreach($searchTerms as $term)
{
    $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%');
}

$results = $query->get();
```

}

Comment: This is mainly Javascript/Ajax, add ajax to your tags to get more help.

Comment: Also, did you try to work something out?

Comment: @MinaYoussef: ill add the tags, i tried few tutorials from youtube but doesn't seem working.

Comment: @amarnasan thank you for adding the tags

Comment: @ramtawker This will most likely be closed unless you can show the code you used and explain the issue you are having.

Comment: @MinaYoussef https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWGJA_SN2O9t5DSlz7PTwAru

Comment: @MinaYoussef i have tried the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return your results

```
return $results;
```